# PHP Echo Returns Blank Page

Tags: php

I have "checks" in here and if something happens, it will `echo` a phrase like `The username you supplied is already in use` or whatever. When it DOES display it though, it'll only display it on a blank page with that text. What is wrong here?

PHP

```
<?php
    include('./dbconnect/global.php');

    if ($_POST['register']) {
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['username']));
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['password']));
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['email']));

        if (!$username||!$password||!$email)
            echo "PLease Fill in The Required Fields";
        else {
            //check if username is taken
            $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
            if (mysql_num_rows($check) >= 1)
                echo "The Username you Supplied Is Already in Use! <a href='./register'>Back</a>";
            $check2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
            if (mysql_num_rows($check) >= 1)
                echo "The Email you Supplied Is Already in Use! <a href='./register'>Back</a>";
            else {
                $password2 = md5($password);
                $register = mysql_query("value and stuff)") or die(mysql_error());
                echo "Thanks for registering, $username! <a href='./index'>Home</a>";
            }
        }
    }

    else {
?>
```

HTML

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>CoreCrafters</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">

</head>

<body>

    <?php include('./include/nbar.php') ?>

    <div id="main">

        <div id="register">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <form action="register" method="POST">
                    Username
                    <br />
                    <input type="username" name="username">
                    <br />
                    Password
                    <br />
                    <input type="password" name="password">
                    <br />
                    Email
                    <br />
                    <input type="email" name="email">
                    <br /><br />
                    <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <?php include('./include/footer.php') ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Ending PHP (From ELSE at end)

```
<?php
    }
?>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #EEE;
}

#headerbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}

a {
    color: #069;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

a:hover { 
    color: #c00;
}

#nav {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
}

#nav li {
    float: left;
}

#nav li a {
    color: #069;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#footer {
    width: 94%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-right: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#main {
    width: 94%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    min-height: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid #DDD;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#register {
    width: 15%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #CCC;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
}

#logbar {
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
    min-height: 36px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    background-color: #DDD;
}
```

As requested, I posted most of the page onto here.

Comment: Your code examples make little sense. Welcome to SO.

Comment: There, I just added 99% of the code.

Comment: I would recommend `isset($_POST['register'])` and `empty($username)||empty($password)||empty($email)`.

Comment: What is you error level set to in your php.ini

Comment: I never created/knew about a php.ini script. Should I have one?

Comment: It should be there probably /etc in your distro. It controls behavior of PHP if error level is set to production type levels it will not show any errors which is why you get a blank page. http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

Comment: This the one I was referring too http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webpage has no content except that echo, so it is echo-ing it on a blank page because you told it to.

- **Update**: Code

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html class="no-js">
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- UXSS UTF-7 (IE6) prevention -->
      <title>CoreCrafters</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php @include('./include/nbar.php'); ?>
  <div id="main">
      <div id="register">
          <div id="wrapper">
              <form method="POST">
                  Username<br /><input type="username" name="username"><br />
                  Password<br /><input type="password" name="password"><br />
                  Email<br /><input type="email" name="email"><br /><br />
                  <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
              </form>
          </div>
  <?php
  @include('./dbconnect/global.php');

  if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
      if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['email'])) {
          die('Please fill out the required fields.');
      } else {
          $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "'");
          if (mysql_num_rows($query)) { die('The username you provided is already in use!'); }

          $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']) . "'");
          if (mysql_num_rows($query)) { die('The email you provided is already in use!'); }

          /** Insert values **/

          echo 'Thanks for registering, ' . htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES) . '!'; /** Normal XSS prevention **/
     }
  }
  ?>
      </div>
  </div>
  <?php @include('./include/footer.php'); ?>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: It also has HTML in the body, but I thought it would be an error on the PHP.

Comment: Could you post all your html/css/php/js?

Comment: Done. All of it needed to display 99% of the page is there.

Comment: Does this code solve your issue? http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HPxG8XpN - Added additional security features as well.

Comment: That update is a bit messy; you should actually end the div, body, and html after the PHP. So, the output is still in the body.

Comment: Thank you so much! Looks MUCH better than before, and thanks for the better security.

Comment: I had them because I tested the code locally, do not have his includes. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing semicolons for your **include** statements (inside the HTML block). Such as:

```
<?php include('./include/footer.php'); ?>
```

If that doesn't solve it, you should check your error log. A completely blank page is often what you get when the PHP parser was unable to parse your code.